# How to insert into a map to a list of lists in kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have this map to lists of lists:

```
val bandMap: Map<Int, List<List<String>>> = mutableMapOf()
```

How do I insert into this list?

I have something like this so far:

```
bandMap[2].add()
```

this will insert a 2 as the key. I need to put something inside of

```
 add()
```

to insert values into the first and second list now as a value pair, such as

```
rsrp: -120,-90,-50,-60; rsrq:-10,-4,-6
```

The catch is that I don't know what the values are, and am trying to add them into a list one by one. For example, add to rsrp list under band 4, -12, now add to rsrq list under band 4, -5. Is there a way to add these one by one without adding the lists all at once?

Thanks,

Comment: You are creating a `mutableMap` but are referencing it as a regular `Map` object. Update your `map` to `val bandMap: MutableMap<Int, List<List<String>>> = mutableMapOf()` to make it `mutable`

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to map a band number to a list of rsrp's rsrq's, etc. The key being the band, the list of lists being an rsrp number list, rsrq number list, etc. Then, you might have another band with the same lists of lists.